# Deploying Tensroflow Library as AWS Lambda Layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to deploy **Tensorflow** (specifically: `libtensorflow.so.1, libtensorflow.so.1.14.0, libtensorflow_framework.so.1, libtensorflow_framework.so.1.14.0`) as **AWS Lambda Layer**. I am getting following error:

```
An error occurred: TensorflowLambdaLayer - Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: d8668bfa-a61c-473c-aeb0-62bff3aa852f).
```

How can I change these .so files by deleting some of their content that is irrelevant for my Lambda function which utilizes Tensorflow Lambda Layer?

Comment: Maybe investigate what others have done to package TF on Lambda, for example https://github.com/ryfeus/lambda-packs and https://github.com/lucleray/tensorflow-lambda. Or consider training and deploying your model to SageMaker hosting and make your Lambda function a client of your SageMaker-hosted endpoint.